# Terraform - How to find objects in a list?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to retrieve elements/objects from a list, that fulfill certain condition.

Example list:

```
{
  "kubernetes": [
    {
      "service_1": {
        "cluster": "dev",
        "...": "..."
      }
    },
    {
      "service_2": {
        "cluster": "prd",
        "...": "..."
      }
    },
    {
      "service_3": {
        "cluster": "dev",
        "...": "..."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to have new lists that are grouping objects with the dev/prd value of the `cluster` param.

Browsing through collection functions from TF, I see that there is a possibility to retrieve specific element based on argument value using `index()`:

```
output "sublist-dev" {
  value = index(var.kubernetes.*.cluster, "dev")
}
```

unfortunately, it's finding only the first object, and there doesn't seem to be other functions suitable for such a purpose.

Do you know if there are other solutions to that problem? Or how would you approach that?

Comment: I guess you can use `var.kubernetes[*].cluster`

Comment: @Felipe is that `var.kubernetes[*].cluster` proper terraform syntax? something like that gives me an error `An attribute name is required after a dot` on Terraform v0.15.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do in that situation:

```
variable "input_data" {
  default = {
    "kubernetes" : [
      {
        "service_1" : {
          "cluster" : "dev",
          "a" : "111"
        }
      },
      {
        "service_2" : {
          "cluster" : "prd",
          "a" : "222"
        }
      },
      {
        "service_3" : {
          "cluster" : "dev",
          "a" : "333"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

locals {
  filter_input = distinct(flatten([
    for item in var.input_data.kubernetes : [
      for data in item : [ item ] if data.cluster == "dev"
  ]]))
}

output "output" {
  value = local.filter_input
}
```

And a terraform apply on that code looks like:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + output = [
      + {
          + "service_1" = {
              + a       = "111"
              + cluster = "dev"
            }
        },
      + {
          + "service_3" = {
              + a       = "333"
              + cluster = "dev"
            }
        },
    ]
```

Comment: Exactly, just found out that filtering option 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html#filtering-elements

thank you